# Ninject does not trigger method when binding to method?

Tags: c#, .net, ninject

The [**ViewModel**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) depends on a list of MyObject which is bound to a [**Repository**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) method that looks like it never gets called?

**CompositionRoot**

```
public sealed class CompositionRoot {
    public CompositionRoot(IKernel kernel) {
        if (kernel == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("kernel");
        this.kernel = kernel;
    }

    public void ComposeObjectGraph() {
        BindRepositoriesByConvention();
        BindDomainModel();
    }

    private void BindDomainModel() {
        kernel
            .Bind<IList<MyObject>>()
            .ToMethod(ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<IMyObjectsRepository>().FindAllMyObjects())
            .WhenInjectedInto<MyObjectsManagementViewModel>();
    }

    private void BindRepositoriesByConvention() {
        kernel.Bind(s => s
            .FromThisAssembly()
            .SelectAllClasses()
            .EndingWith("Repository")
            .BindSelection((type, baseType) => type
                .GetInterfaces()
                .Where(iface => iface.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))));
    }

    private readonly IKernel kernel;
}
```

**MyObjectsManagementViewModel**

```
public class MyObjectsManagementViewModel {
    public MyObjectsViewModel(IList<MyObject> model) {
        if (model == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("model");
        Model = model;
    }

    public MyObject Current { get; set; }
    public IList<MyObject> Model { get; set; }
}
```

**MyObjectsRepository**

```
public class MyObjectsRepository 
    : NHibernateRepository<MyObject>
    , IMyObjectsRepository {
    public MyObjectsRepository(ISession session) : base(session) { }

    public IList<MyObject> FindAllMyObjects() { return GetAll(); }
}
```

The `NHibernateRepository` is an abstract class which exposes protected members allowing one to customize the method names through interfaces like `IMyObjectsRepository` to state a more domain friendly name, let's say.

The objects mappings work fine as [**NHibernate**](http://nhibernate.info/) has properly created and updated the underlying database doing [**Domain-Driven Design**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design).

The problem is definitely around my understanding or misuse (I believe) of [**Ninject**](http://www.ninject.org/) while binding the list of MyObject to the **Repository** method.

- I've put a breakpoint to the **FindAllMyObjects** method, and it never gets hit?
- and the list of MyObjects being injected into the MyObjectsManagementViewModel constructor is always an empty one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue here is you are binding to a type (`IList<T>`) that Ninject isn't expecting to resolve. the simplest solution is to instead bind to a Func that will return the object(s) you want.

for example:

```
kernel
    .Bind<Func<IList<MyObject>>>()
    .ToMethod(ctx => () => ctx.Kernel.Get<IMyObjectsRepository>().FindAllMyObjects())
    .WhenInjectedInto<MyObjectsManagementViewModel>();
```

then:

```
public MyObjectsViewModel(Func<IList<MyObject>> model) {
    if (model == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("model");
    Model = model();
}
```

this effectively does a lazy-load of the items from the repository when the MyObjectsViewModel object is constructed.

another alternative (which may be more clear and better design) would be to create a new interface like `IMyObjectProvider`, which is responsible only for finding and returning the correct data. then that interface would be injected into your viewmodel instead of the actual model objects.

Comment: Wouldn't be injecting the `IMyObjectProvider` the same as injecting the `IMyObjectRepository` ? I read somewhere on the Internet that injecting a repository into a view model class was considered an anti-pattern, isn't it?

Comment: really, if you are using a viewmodel the way it's supposed to be used by a MVC or MVP pattern, it shouldn't have *any* dependencies. you would have a Controller or Presenter that is creating and filling it with data from the repository (or wherever). however, you asked a question about why Ninject was not filling the request.