# Constructor or Property Injection for View Models?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, viewmodel, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I recently posted a question about Ninject not injecting expected **`IList<T>`** upon a repository method call which returns an **`IList<T>`** into a view model constructor which given answer is to inject some kind of repository or the like.

- [**Ninject does not trigger method when binding to method?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29100858/162167)

However, I have already read somewhere that injecting a repository or the like into a view model's constructor was considered an anti-pattern (don't remember for what reasons, though).

Mr. [**Dave Thieben**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218136/dave-thieben) says that if I used the ViewModel pattern the way it is supposed to in MVC or MVP, than the view model shall have no dependencies injected into its constructor, and instead it should be filled through Property Injection from within the Controller or Presenter.

Following the rule "inject exactly what that class requires to fulfill its responsibility", all what the list ViewModel needs is a list of user objects, based on what's managed. So why just not have it injected right away though Constructor Injection, instead of having it injected through Property Injection?

Answer (score 9):

Plainly and simply, the view model should have no knowledge of your repository; in other words, it should have no dependency on your repository, regardless of how you might inject it.

Your repository should be injected into your controller, and your controller should set the view model's property, performing whatever query necessary. The key is that the actor here needs to be your controller, not your view model. The view model is a passive class, just meant to hold data the view needs, whereas it's the actual job of the controller to wire everything up, issuing queries and such to fetch data as necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Chris Pratt. Besides I wonder, if the ViewModel needs a list or something to display on the view, and that this is actually a dependency, plus let's say language configuration for labels to be displayed in the user's language, the ViewModel needs those information to do its job properly. So from what I understand, the ViewModel is an example of where Property Injection is more suitable, is that correct? If so, I'd like to understand why Property Injection is best for the ViewModel Pattern, and Construction Injection for other types. Thanks in advance (+1)!